# How to get data by id from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object Like

[image]

How to get single row by Id?

Comment: use index to get it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Array#find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function and pass a condition into it like

`arr.find(item => item.id === 1)`

**Example**

```js
const users = [
  {id: 1, name: 'A'},
  {id: 2, name: 'B'},
];

const user = users.find(item => item.id === 1);

console.log(user);
```

Comment: var abc = arr.find(item => item.id === 2053) 
abc "Undefined"

Comment: Your property name is `Id` not `id`, with capital letter

Comment: var abc = arr.find(item => item.id == 2053)    "==" works but why?

Comment: Because `==` will try to cast your id's into boolean value, and if the number is not `0`, it will be casted into `true` so actually you use `true == true`. But this is logically wrong. Use `===` instead of `==` and proper property names

Comment: var abc = dataArr.find(item => item.Id == elem); ** typeCast elem ??? **

Comment: Man, use `===` this syntax and `Id` property to get the correct results. Anything else will give you logically wrong values

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
var item = yourArray.find(item => item.id === 2053);
```

DEMO

```js
const yourArray = [
  {Id: 2053, title: 'sass'},
  {Id: 2054, title: 'sdss'},
];
const found = yourArray.find(item => item.Id ===2053);
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo can also use 
`var requiredItem = array.filter(i => i.id == 2054)`

Example

```js
var arrayNew = [
  {id: 2053, name: 'sxsxs'},
  {id: 2054, name: 'sss'}  
];

var requiredItem = arrayNew.filter(i => i.id == 2054);

console.log(requiredItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = [{
 "id" : 1,
 "Title" : "Hi"
},{
"id" : 11,
 "Title" : "Hello"
}]

function filterById(ids) {
  return  obj.filter((obj) => {return obj.id == ids})  
}

console.log(filterById(11))
```